# eclipse/zk: is it possible to prevent the *.zul editor formatter from inserting new lines between tags and text?

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting, zk

I tried [asking this question on the zk forum](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/88092/eclipse-zul-editor-formatter-messes-up-my-whitespace-line-breaks/), but did not get an answer.

I use zk studio. I really like being able to auto format my *.zul files (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>). But whenever I have a link between parentheses or at the end of a sentence, the autoformat moves the link tag on a separate line. This causes spaces to appear before and after the link.

[image]

Is there a way to keep using autoformat but avoid this problem? It drives me crazy :-(

I tried playing with the settings but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the max line width property in the formatting settings

Comment: Are you sure about this (does it work for you)? My max line width settings are at 140 characters (for both the java formatter and XML formatter). I cannot see any line width setting below the "ZK" node.